# Add last filled field in column (r language)

Tags: r

I have my table (input):

```
user_id  level1 level2 level3 level4
Rob      123456 456456 NA     12345
Mike     23445  NA     NA     NA
Stan     23423  345345 NA     NA
```

And I want to create column with last `levelName` that has value (output):

```
user_id  level1 level2 level3 level4  lastLevel
Rob      123456 456456 NA     12345   level4
Mike     23445  NA     NA     NA      level1
Stan     23423  345345 NA     NA      level2
```

THX!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `is.na` and `max.col`:

```
df$lastLevel <- names(df)[max.col(!is.na(df), "last")]
> df
#  user_id level1 level2 level3 level4 lastLevel
#1     Rob 123456 456456     NA  12345    level4
#2    Mike  23445     NA     NA     NA    level1
#3    Stan  23423 345345     NA     NA    level2
```

Comment: all my `lastLevel` column filled by `lastLevel`. I enter this `tableLevel$lastLevel <- names(tableLevel)[max.col(!is.na(tableLevel), "last")]`

Comment: @Smasell, that's strange because it works as expected with your sample data, as you see in my post. Perhaps you can provide a `dput(head(tableLevel))`

Comment: Ok! Anyway THX for help)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply`

```
 df1$lastlevel <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) tail(names(df1)[-1][!is.na(x)],1))
 df1
 #  user_id level1 level2 level3 level4 lastlevel
 #1     Rob 123456 456456     NA  12345    level4
 #2    Mike  23445     NA     NA     NA    level1
 #3    Stan  23423 345345     NA     NA    level2
```

---

Or using `rowMaxs` from `matrixStats`

```
 library(matrixStats)
 names(df1)[-1][rowMaxs(col(df1[-1]) * !is.na(df1[-1]))]
 #[1] "level4" "level1" "level2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
df$lastLevel <- names(df)[apply(df, 1, function(x) max(which(!is.na(x))))]
df
  user_id level1 level2 level3 level4 lastLevel
1     Rob 123456 456456     NA  12345    level4
2    Mike  23445     NA     NA     NA    level1
3    Stan  23423 345345     NA     NA    level2
```